# Ansible Keyword 'ignore_unreachable'

Tags: ansible

I have seen in ansible doc that the keyword 'ignore_unreachable' can be used to allow the playbook to continue and quit without errors if the host (or some hosts) unreachable.

However. if i use this keyword in a play, in a role, in a task it always gives me a warning

[WARNING]: Ignoring invalid attribute: ignore_unreachable

I can't figure out what the problem is. Any helpful tip  would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Ansible >= 2.7. See [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords).